# Separate a column into multiple columns using tidyr::separate with sep=""

Tags: r, tidyr

```
df <- data.frame(category = c("X", "Y"), sequence = c("AAT.G", "CCG-T"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
 category sequence
1        X     AAT.G
2        Y     CCG-T
```

I want to separate the column `sequence` into 5 columns (one for each character). I tried to do that with `tidyr::separate` but it internally uses `stringi::stri_split_regex` which doesn't accept an empty string as a separator (although the `sep` argument should take a regex).

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, sequence, into = paste0("V", 1:5), sep="")

Error: Values not split into 5 pieces at 1, 2
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In stringi::stri_split_regex(value, sep, n_max) :
  empty search patterns are not supported
2: In stringi::stri_split_regex(value, sep, n_max) :
  empty search patterns are not supported
```

Expected output looks like this:

```
  category V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1        X  A  A  T  .  G
2        Y  C  C  G  -  T
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, sequence, into=paste0('V', 1:5), '(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)')
#  category V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1        X  A  A  T  .  G
#2        Y  C  C  G  -  T
```

Or create a delimiter with `gsub` and use that as `sep` for the `separator`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(sequence=gsub('(?<=.)(?=.)', ',', sequence, perl=TRUE)) %>% 
   separate(sequence, into=paste0('V', 1:5), sep=",")
#  category V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1        X  A  A  T  .  G
#2        Y  C  C  G  -  T
```

Or you can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
setnames(cSplit(df, 'sequence', '', stripWhite=FALSE),
             2:6, paste0('V', 1:5))[]
#   category V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1:        X  A  A  T  .  G
#2:        Y  C  C  G  -  T
```

Comment: It's a bit non elegant when you have many columns. I would have to use regex=paste(rep("(.)", n), collapse=""). But it does the job! Thank you!

Comment: @vitor Updated with a possible `separate` solution.

Answer (score 3):

`sep` can be an integer vector. It would be sufficient to use `sep=1:4` but the 5 works too and it looks a bit better.

```
df %>% separate(sequence, into = paste0("V", 1:5), sep = 1:5)
```

giving:

```
  category V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1        X  A  A  T  .  G
2        Y  C  C  G  -  T
```

Comment: Very interesting approach! Do you have a reference that describes how does it works?

Comment: Try the help file: `?separate`

Comment: Ah, missed the last paragraph for `sep` somehow.